# AWS Glue ETL Job Missing collection name

Tags: mongodb, etl, aws-glue

I have data catalog tables generated by crawlers one is data source from mongodb, and second is datasource Postgres sql (rds). Crawlers running successfully & connections test working.
I am trying to define an ETL job from mongodb to postgres sql (simple transform).
In the job I defined source as AWS Glue Data Catalog (mongodb) and target as Data catalog Postgres.
When I run the job I get this error:

**IllegalArgumentException: Missing collection name. Set via the 'spark.mongodb.input.uri' or 'spark.mongodb.input.collection' property**

It looks like this is related to the mongodb part. I tried to set the 'database' and 'collection' parameters in the data catalog tables and it didn't help

Script generated for source is:

```
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1653400663056 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
database="data-catalog-db",
table_name="data-catalog-table",
transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1653400663056"
```

What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just add the parameter below.

```
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1653400663056 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
database="data-catalog-db",
table_name="data-catalog-table",
transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1653400663056"
additional_options = {"database":"data-catalog-db", 
            "collection":"data-catalog-table"}
```

Additional parameters can be found on the AWS page

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-mongodb.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).